# Subscript out of bounds in correlation matrix

Tags: r, correlation

I am working on a correlation matrix (`corm`) of 606 columns by 606 rows, and I have a variable called (`X`) that contains some column names. I want to pick these columns from the (`corm`).

```
> print(X)
 [1] "VL"         "IM"         "2_EA"    "Av"       
 [5] "Cit"        "Wap"        "Rp"      "R"      
 [9] "H2e"        "Wp"         "As"      "2"        
 [13] "HS"        "Wep"        "W"       "p"
```

I apply the following command

```
corm2 <- corm[,X]
```

and I get this:

```
Error: subscript out of bounds
```

Any clue what is going wrong here?

Comment: all(X %in% dimnames(corm)[[2]])?

Comment: FALSE, what does that mean? :D

Comment: Some of the names in `X` do not show up as column names of your `corm` matrix. Probably a typo. Run `setdiff(X, colnames(corm))` to find which ones.

Comment: Flodel thanks fort the command, Yes i found the ones that do not match. I'll look up the reason why they they have changed. I also need to check if the problem is resolved after editing the names in the variable X.

Comment: The issue is resolved, I don't get the error anymore. Thanks themel, Arun and Flodel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning that comment into an answer:

`Error: subscript out of bounds` happens because some of the names in `X` are not column names to your `corm` matrix. In other words, you are trying to extract inexistent columns, hence the error message.

It is probably because of a typo. You can run `setdiff(X, colnames(corm))` to find out the culprit(s).